# How to force to center the table captions?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

i want to center the table captions.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I recommend to use the [caption](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package. It provides features for justification, also for centering, such as

```
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
```

It offers many features, just have a look at its comprehensive [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf).

Comment: Kottwit, for my long table captions, i'm using \newline to make some comments about the tables. But i want these start from left is that possible? this is caption \newline this is more explanation (should be left aligned.) is there a way to do it?

Comment: @berkay: Using `\newline` inside a paragraph which will be typeset centered is usually a bad idea. Better use \\ instead which should work under such conditions, too.

Comment: I use `justification` but not solved.  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YGNgtbKNBH/  https://ibb.co/fKDX18

Comment: Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected, usage of the caption package is not recommended. See the caption package documentation for explanation.  (I use OverLeaf with XeLaTex Compiler)

Answer (score 20):

Note: If you do not want to change the justification for the whole document you can use `\captionsetup{}` within a particular figure and it will only change the captions within that environment.
Other than `centering` you may also want to try `centerlast`.

```
\usepackage{caption}
...
\begin{figure}
   ...
   \captionsetup{justification=centering}
   \caption{. . . }
\end{figure}
```