# How to force the caption of a table in order to set it in center

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Although, I saw the following post in order to do that : [How to force to center the table captions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16128/how-to-force-to-center-the-table-captions), I coudn't find a proper way to set the table's caption. How can I force this action?

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[font=Large,labelfont=bf,justification=centering]{caption}
\begin{document}

asdasdasdad sadasdasdasdadasd asdasdasdasdafenm jejfnewjfnejfne nfjewnfwnfwfwqf
\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-0.5cm}{}
\resizebox{0.6\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | c | c |  c |  c |  c | c |  c |  c |  }

\cline{2-11} 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \textbf{Telestrada} & \textbf{Telestrada} & \textbf{Telestrada} & \textbf{Telestrada} &
\textbf{Telestrada} & \textbf{Telestrada} & \textbf{Telestrada} & 
\textbf{Telestrada} & \textbf{Telestrada} & \textbf{Telestrada} \\

\hline
  \textbf{LOC} & 5 & 5 & 6 & 5 & - & 5 & 6 & 5 & 6 & 5  \\
\hline
  \textbf{VS} & 8 & 5 & 9 & 8 & 9 & 8 & 9 & 8 & 9 & 8 \\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{fig:text}text experiment experiment experiment experiment}
\end{minipage} }

\end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}
\\
sdasdada asdasdas adasdasdasd
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your caption is resized to `0.6\textwidth` as it lies inside the `minipage` Same thing happens to `tabular` too but since it is tooo long we don't notice it. Put the caption outside the `\resizebox` and use `font=small` in the option of `caption`. You may also control the width by `width=\textwidth`.

Code:

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[font=normalsize,labelfont=bf,justification=centering]{caption}
%%% use `font=normalsize`. can also use `width=\textwidth`
\begin{document}

asdasdasdad sadasdasdasdadasd asdasdasdasdafenm jejfnewjfnejfne nfjewnfwnfwfwqf
\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-0.5cm}{}
\resizebox{0.6\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | c | c |  c |  c |  c | c |  c |  c |  }

\cline{2-11}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \textbf{Telestrada} & \textbf{Telestrada} & \textbf{Telestrada} & \textbf{Telestrada} &
\textbf{Telestrada} & \textbf{Telestrada} & \textbf{Telestrada} &
\textbf{Telestrada} & \textbf{Telestrada} & \textbf{Telestrada} \\

\hline
  \textbf{LOC} & 5 & 5 & 6 & 5 & - & 5 & 6 & 5 & 6 & 5  \\
\hline
  \textbf{VS} & 8 & 5 & 9 & 8 & 9 & 8 & 9 & 8 & 9 & 8 \\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{minipage} 
}
\end{adjustwidth}
%% put caption outside here
\caption{\label{fig:text}text experiment experiment experiment experiment experiment experiment experiment}
\end{table}

%% don't use a \\ here but leave an empty l;ine
sdasdada asdasdas adasdasdasd
\end{document}
```

[image]